# Warning: is_file() [function.is-file]: Unable to find the wrapper "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? Arch linux

Tags: php, linux, ssl, openssl

I'm getting this error when I'm trying to send email with smtp.gmail.com with switf mailler in arch linux with PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze15 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Mar  4 2013 13:11:17). I verified with phpinfo() and already have openssl module.

```
openssl
OpenSSL support enabled
OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
```

I'm tested with tls and the same error appear, but with the word tls in double quotes.

With iptables, the ports are already open:

```
ACCEPT  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:465 
ACCEPT  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:587
```

When I'm trying with telnet it's just working sometime ! What could be the problem ?